# Atribuição de responsabilidades no MVC

Tags: laravel, mvc

Estou iniciando o trabalho com MVC, mais especificamente com Laravel e o Eloquent (o ORM embutido no Laravel).

Estudei e continuo estudando o padrão MVC e suas vantagens. No entanto, na prática, fiquei com algumas dúvidas de onde atribuir as devidas responsabilidades. Principalmente pela flexibilidade do framework e das várias dezenas de variações do MVC.

Vamos lá: na minha aplicação utilizarei métodos que trarão por exemplo noticias em destaque. Tal método deve ficar no Model ou no meu Controller? Por quê?

Comment: No model, pense nele como uma ponte entre você e o bd.

Answer (score 3):

Pense que as controllers são apenas um dos pontos de entradas para a sua aplicação, e por isso devem possuir o mínimo de código possível. Digo isso porque pode haver outros pontos de entrada, como comandos, APIs etc.

Em geral a maior parte do código nas minhas aplicações reside nas models (que, pra mim, são representações das entidades da aplicação, que por sua vez são replicadas no banco de dados); nos repositórios (responsáveis por trazer uma instância ou uma coleção de entidades); e nos serviços (que são responsáveis por executar uma tarefa específica na aplicação).

Voltando à sua pergunta, você diz que quer buscar notícias em destaque. Eu faria da seguinte maneira:

1. Ter um método no controlador mapeado à rota (por exemplo) `/noticias/destaques`. O método poderia se chamar `NoticiasController::destaquesAction`.
2. Ter uma entidade `Noticia`, que representa a notícia no seu banco de dados, e uma classe `NoticiasRepository`, responsável por trazer uma notícia ou uma coleção delas.
3. Ter um método `NoticiasRepository::getNoticiasEmDestaque` que retorna uma coleção de notícias em destaque, ordenadas a seu gosto.
4. Por fim, chamar esse método a partir do seu controlador e renderizá-la na view.

Assim é a forma que costumo desenvolver minhas aplicações. Se tiver alguma opinião a respeito, é só falar. :)

Comment: Sei que a publicação é um pouco antiga, porém seria correto eu chamar de NoticiasDAO ao invés de NoticiasRepository?